# Sharp Ratio Maximization, Closed Forms

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to get a closed form for the following first order conditions (n=4):

[image]

Here's the [nb-File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyxv1hqx0o4vn44/variance233.nb?dl=0).

The code is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"]; CloseKernels[];
n = 6
alph := Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, 2, n}]
blph := Table[Subscript[b, i], {i, 1, n}]
ConstantArray[0, n - 1]
alph2 := Table[Subscript[σ, i, j], {i, 2, n}, {j, 2, i - 1}]
alph3 := Table[Subscript[σ, j, i], {i, 2, n}, {j, 2, n}]
alph4 := Table[Subscript[σ, i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
alph5 := Table[Subscript[σ, j, i], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
alph55 := Table[Subscript[s, j, i], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
alph56 := Table[Subscript[d, i], {i, 1, n}]
alph57 := Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, n}]
alph58 := Table[Subscript[k, i], {i, 1, n}]
alph59 := Table[Subscript[l, i], {i, 1, n}]
alph60 := Table[Subscript[g, i], {i, 1, n}]
(*Riskless bond with no covariances*)
Do[Subscript[σ, 1, i] = 0, {i, 1, n}]
Do[Subscript[σ, i, 1] = 0, {i, 1, n}]

n = 3
alph55
alph5
(*Covariance same when index interchanged*)
Do[Subscript[σ, j, i] = alph5[[j, i]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
alph5 // MatrixForm
Table[Subscript[R, i], {i, 1, n}]
(*First Order Conditions*)
Do[Subscript[a, k] = 
   D[((Sum[Subscript[R, i]*Subscript[w, i], {i, 2, n}]) - Subscript[R,
        1])/((Sum[
         Subscript[σ, i, 
          j]*(Subscript[w, i])*(Subscript[w, j]), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, 
          n}]))^0.5, {Subscript[w, k]}], {k, 2, n}];
bebe = Table[alph[[i]] == 0, {i, 1, n - 1}]
alph2;
(*Get vector of Covariances without Variances (i,i)*)
For[i = 2, i <= n, i++; 
 alph3 = DeleteCases[Flatten[alph3], Subscript[σ, i, i]]]
(*Set equal FOC i and i+1*)
bebe2 = Table[alph[[i]] - alph[[i + 1]] == 0, {i, 1, n - 2}];
bebe3 = bebe2 /. 
   Flatten[{Subscript[R, 1] -> 1.02, Subscript[R, 2] -> 1.05, 
     Subscript[R, 3] -> 1.1, Subscript[σ, 2, 2] -> 0.1, 
     Subscript[σ, 3, 3] -> 0.05, 
     Table[alph3[[i]] -> 0, {i, 1, Length[alph3]}]}];
sol2 = Normal[
   NSolve[
    Flatten[{bebe2, {Sum[Subscript[w, i], {i, 2, n}] == 1}, 
      Table[Subscript[w, i] >= 0, {i, 2, n}], 
      Table[Subscript[R, i] > Subscript[R, 1], {i, 2, n}], 
      Table[Subscript[σ, i, i] > 0, {i, 2, n}]}, 1], 
    Table[Subscript[w, i], {i, 2, n}], Reals], ConditionalExpression];
sol2 /. Flatten[{Subscript[R, 2] -> 1.05, Subscript[R, 3] -> 1.1, 
    Subscript[σ, 2, 2] -> 0.1, 
    Subscript[σ, 3, 3] -> 0.05, 
    Table[alph3[[i]] -> 0, {i, 1, Length[alph3]}]}];

sol = NSolve[
  Flatten[{bebe3, {Sum[Subscript[w, i], {i, 2, n}] == 1}, 
    Table[Subscript[w, i] >= 0, {i, 2, n}]}, 1], 
  Table[Subscript[w, i], {i, 2, n}], Reals]
```

In this example R1 is the riskless asset's return and has no variance or covariance to the other assets. 
The Closed Form exists for n=3 (therefore two assets composition weights can be found). I am running the code now for 1.5 days and still no end. Numerically it works.

Thanks for any ideas why the closed form either can't be found or takes too long.

Comment: chris, please post the relevant code (and only the relevant code!) within your question rather than linking the whole notebook. In addition to the extra step one has to take in order to help you, there are also security concerns about opening a notebook from an unknown source (may contain malicious code, etc). Your question will attract more attention and better-quality answers if you make it as easy as possible for people to play with your code in a minimal but working example.

Comment: Thanky you MarcoB for the recommendation. I've included the minimal working example.